# Problem on running Script on host after connecting

Tags: linux, shell-script, ssh, expect

I am new to linux scripting. Please help. I searched on below a lot but was not able to find appropriate answer :

I am trying to make a script which I will later schedule as cronjob, so that it keeps running on backend and stores results in a file say test.txt

Main points of script are below :

it connects to a host through ssh and then runs a few commands on that host and saves the results in a file.The script is connecting to host successfully but not running commands automatically on host. Script is as below :

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh aspen

expect "password: "

send "PASSWORD\r"

expect "$ "

send "/bin/sh /home/target/Script.sh >>test.txt"

expect "$ "

send "exit\r"
```

But when I run this script it doesn't save complete output on test.txt 
Second thing is I want this output file on my own system not on host . Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: Please help anybody !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to achieve several things here:

1. Connect to a host without user interaction
2. Run some script and save its output

To 1:

It is best to generate an ssh key pair with `ssh-keygen` and store the public key on your host machine. Generate it without using a password, then `ssh` won't ask you for one on connection. Use

```
client$ ssh -i <keyfile>
```

to connect to your host using your generated keys. See also ssh(1) and sshd(8) section AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT on how to add your public key on the host to be recognized, which is mainly:

```
host$ cat <keyfile>.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(This has to be done on the host!)

Remark: The private key is equivalent to a password! Make sure you keep it safe such that only the cron job can use it. Look at sshd(8) section AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT, as it shows you how you can restrict the usage of your generated key pair such that it can only run your script!

To 2:

You can run `ssh` with a shell command as an argument including I/O redirections. Just run e.g. `/home/target/Script.sh 2>&1` and save the output. The full command looks like this:

```
client$ ssh -i <keyfile> user@host '/home/target/Script.sh 2>&1' >>test.txt
```

`test.txt` resides on your own machine, the script is run on the host.

Remark: The script directs its output to standard out. No special handling needed on the host (except for the redirection '2>&1' to also capture output to standard error.)

Comment: Thanx for your response . I'll just check it . Thanks again..